# ng-click do not work when a template bound using ng-bind-html-unsafe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Why below input button do not call `login()` function inside `InitCtrl` controller?

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="mvc-module" class="ng-scope"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <script src="/SpringMVC/static/todo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="InitCtrl" ng-bind-html-unsafe="mainPage" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
    <!------ this part of code is injected by binding model of Angularjs --> 
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" ng-click="login()" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">
</div>
    <!--- end of injection --->
</div>
</body></html>
```

and this is `todo.js` :

```
function InitCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.login = function () {
    console.log("In login!");
    $http.post("login", {password: $scope.password, username: $scope.username}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.mainPage = data;
            console.log("successfully logged to login");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error in post");
        });

    };

    $http.get("login").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.mainPage = data;
    });
}
```

And this is not working fiddler version of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/pooyaho/M8krc/4/

Comment: probably because you're not recompiling it. can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @EduardGamonal Server side program is Spring MVC, How can I deploy it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Where are you loading the angular components?

Comment: @Пуя hardcode things...

Comment: @Пуя sorry for delay, i solved you problem, do you still need the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to insert HTML with `ng-bind-html-unsafe` therefore `ng-click` doesn't work. To make it work we need to *compile* this source by using `$compile` service.

So lets create "compilator":

```
.directive( 'compileData', function ( $compile ) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

      var elmnt;

      attrs.$observe( 'template', function ( myTemplate ) {
        if ( angular.isDefined( myTemplate ) ) {
          // compile the provided template against the current scope
          elmnt = $compile( myTemplate )( scope );

            element.html(""); // dummy "clear"

          element.append( elmnt );
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

after, let's create dummy `factory` that simulates response from server:

```
.factory( 'tempService', function () {
  return function () {

    // $http.post("login", {password: $scope.password, username: $scope.username}).
     //   success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //       
     //       console.log("successfully logged to login");
     //       return data;
     //   }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      //      console.log("error in post");
      //      return "error";   
      //  });


    // obviously would be $http      
    return '<form class= "form-signin" >' +
        '<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>' +
        '<input type = "text" class= "input-block-level" placeholder = "User name" ng-model = "username" >' +
        '<input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">' +
        '<label class="checkbox">' +
        '<input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" ng-model="remember"> Remember me' +
        '</label>' +
        '<input type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="login()" value="Sign in">' +
        '</form>';
  };
});
```

And at last let's add our directive to HTML:

```
 <div compile-data template="{{mainPage}}"></div>
```

For sure, we need to register in controller  our `factory` and `directive`:

```
$scope.mainPage= tempService();
```

You can find working example here: <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/551/)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, It loads the login page inside the main div. take a look at my example url

Comment: That's awesome, thx for sharing! Is it also possible to put additional controllers and directives in a `<script>` tag inside the template?

Comment: Sure, since you compile it, you can define everything.

Comment: Could you help me with this? I think my problem is, that the html is compiled before the `<script>` tag is evaluated. So the controller I have defined inside the `<script>` tag is not defined at that point.

Comment: @Felix sorry, its not refer to current question/answer. Please open new question

Comment: @MaximShoustin you're right. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134725/adding-controller-in-script-tag-when-using-angulars-compile. Maybe you've got some idea?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` is removed in newer versions of angular-js and will throw an error if you use it.