# Adding controller in script tag when using angular's $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-compile

When `$compile`-ing an angular HTML template string I'm trying to put **additional controllers and directives inside a `<script>` tag** and use those in the HTML template.

This way I'm essentially trying to implement some sort of **plug-in-mechanism**, so that I can load external files that augment my app's functionality.

The `<script>` tag does actually get evaluated, but my problem is, that the HTML template compilation takes place before the evaluation of the JavaScript. So the compiler complains about missing controllers.

---

Example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8oZYhRHAjP84ecnl6hG3?p=preview

This example throws an error: `Error: Argument 'Controller' is not a function, got undefined`

If you delete lines 15-18 (the HTML that references the created conroller) in `app.js`, you can see in the console that creating a controller this way does actually work.

Comment: I think a lot of that code should be in a directive but what if you use a two pass system.  First just insert the script part into the page (which doesn't even need to be compiled) and then insert the compiled part

Comment: That's a good idea! I tried it, but without success. See http://plnkr.co/edit/fzmEZlP6bGBJqTOkfApH?p=preview. Maybe it is to late in angular's lifecycle to add a controller?

Comment: Check this question, maybe that will help you get on the right track: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250644/angularjs-loading-a-controller-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to do it based on the solution in [Loading an AngularJS controller dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250644/angularjs-loading-a-controller-dynamically).
Thx @JoseM, @MaximShoustin and @JussiKosunen for your hints and help.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fzmEZlP6bGBJqTOkfApH?p=preview